# MacBook AirでNEUTRINOを使い、音楽制作途中ですがつまずいています。

Tags: macos

あまり機械に強くなく、でも音楽制作をしてみたく
様々な説明サイトや動画を見ながらおこなっているのですが、つまずき先に進めなくなってしまいました。
藁にもすがる思いでこちらのサイトにたどり着き、質問させていただきます。
カテゴリ違いなどでしたら削除しますのでお教え願います。

MacBook Airを使っており、「NEUTRINO」という音楽制作ソフトと「muse score」という楽譜作成ソフトをダウンロードしました。
muse scoreで作成した楽譜を、NEUTRINOのファイル→score→musicxml内のサンプルが3つ入っているファイルに、楽譜のエクスポートはできていると思われます。

Run.shで、BASENAMEの箇所も書き換えています。

このあとMacの「ターミナル」を開き、ここでサイトや動画の説明と同じく `cd Documents/NEUTRNO` と打ちエンター、`sh Run.sh` と打っているのですが、この先が何も出てきません。
他のサイトや動画と見比べても、ターミナルを開いた時に元から入っている文章も違うように感じるのですが・・・。

この場合、どこをどう直すと先へ進めるのでしょうか。
分かる方いましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

**追記:**

ファイルにカーソルを合わせて新規ターミナルを開く、ができていなかったので、こちらを行ったところ、エラーメッセージが出るようになりました。
ただ、ここからまた進めず、楽譜を最初から読み直したり、試しているのですが、同じエラーが出て進めません。

・・追記・・
コメントありがとうございます。遅くなりすみません。

新規ターミナルを開いて cd Documents/NEUTRNO →エンターで sh Run.sh
と打った場合のエラーは下記です。

```
Last login: Wed Jun 30 10:15:53 on console
MacBook-Air:NEUTRINO $ sh Run.sh
18:37 : start MusicXMLtoLabel
    Convert MusicXML to label -> score/musicxml/atamesi.musicxml
[ERR] Cannot open Xml file
[ERROR] failed to load score from MusicXML file : score/musicxml/atamesi.musicxml
18:37 : start NEUTRINO
    error: Can not open full label file.
18:37 : start WORLD
   error: Can not open file.
18:37 : END
MacBook-Air:NEUTRINO $
```

またcd Documents/NEUTRNOなしで、sh Run.shを打つという情報もありましたので
その場合のエラーは以下の通りです。

```
Last login: Wed Jun 30 10:18:26 on ttys000
MacBook-Air:NEUTRINO $ cd Documents/NEUTRNO
-bash: cd: Documents/NEUTRNO: No such file or directory
MacBook-Air:NEUTRINO $ sh Run.sh
19:49 : start MusicXMLtoLabel
    Convert MusicXML to label -> score/musicxml/atamesi.musicxml
[ERR] Cannot open Xml file
[ERROR] failed to load score from MusicXML file : score/musicxml/atamesi.musicxml
19:49 : start NEUTRINO
    error: Can not open full label file.
19:49 : start WORLD
   error: Can not open file.
19:49 : END
MacBook-Air:NEUTRINO $
```

ターミナル内やRun.sh内の書き換え方が問題なのか、そもそもの楽譜ファイルが悪いのか、どこに原因があるのかよく分からない状態です。

Comment: エラーが出ているのであればそのエラー内容も質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: `cd Documents/NEUTRNO` ではなくて `cd Documents/NEUTRINO` では？

Comment: 仰せの通り、NEUTRINOだったようです。私がつまずいていたのは、どうやらエクスポート先を間違っていたようで、エクスポート先が「music XML」、ファイル種類に「非圧縮」を選ぶのが正解のようでした。これで先に進みそうなのですが、ターミナルがなかなか進まず、まだ非完成です。。コメント下さった方、ありがとうございますm(_ _)m